# LEFT JOIN Counting the wrong value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Top of report will show a summary - First row of report summary shows ingot #. Second row of report summary shows % of total tubes inspected that were rejected for ID defects. Third row of report summary shows % of tubes rejected that are ODD tubes (with tube ID ending in 1, 3, 5, 7, 9). Fourth row of report summary shows % of tubes rejected that are EVEN tubes (with tube ID ending in 0,2,4,6,8).

HERE are the tables I am working with
[Tube Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR4K0.png)

[TubeRework Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUCvI.png)

```
SELECT  
Tube.Ingot,
COUNT(DISTINCT Tube.Piece) AS NumberOfTubes,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS NumberOfTubesRejected,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL AND RIGHT(Tube.Piece, 1) % 2 = 1
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS NumberOfOddTubesRejected,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL AND RIGHT(Tube.Piece, 1) % 2 = 0
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS NumberOfEvenTubesRejected,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN reworkcodecount IN (4,5,6)
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS NumberRejectedByIDDefects
FROM dbo.Tube
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
dbo.TubeRework.Tube_#, dbo.TubeRework.ReworkCode_# AS reworkcodecount
FROM dbo.TubeRework
) AS TubeRework_Grouped ON TubeRework_Grouped.Tube_# = dbo.Tube.Tube_#
GROUP BY Tube.Ingot
```

I am trying to select the ingot, and count on the total number of tubes, which is coming out correctly.

The Issue starts on my

```
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END) AS NumberOfTubesRejected
```

If I delete the LEFT JOIN, It works perfectly as expected, and returns 11 NumberOfTubesRejected, which counts the number of time the AcceptedBy Value is NULL. When I dont delete the LEFT JOIN (As I need it to do my last part to grab and return the ingot and tube# that has an ID DEFECT (4-6 value).

Look below as it returns 16 values for NumberOfTubesRejected when I run my query, it should return 11 total if you count the number of times it is null.

[Above Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlD8N.png)

I'm having issues figuring out how to left join a table, and be able to still grab the NumberOfTubesRejected value as the correct value.

Any Tips would be great.

The Expected output would be, but I cant include my last search for the NumberOfIdDefects in the rework table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXt3q.png)

I hope this clears it up.

I need all this data in one report. [Need All this in one report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je0C7.png)Cheers

LEt me know. Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question and add your code, your sampe data and your expected outcome as text, not as an image. Thank you

Comment: Probably what you are after is Count(DISTINCT Tube.piece) but I can't be sure. Your intention is not clear and images are not very helpful on SO. Instead provide sample data and desired output as text (code is better but even a plain text is better image).

Comment: BTW using sum() in a situation that creates 1-to-many results would lead to incorrect results. Do summing separate (and unlikely that is what you need).

Comment: You fell in [The GROUPing pitfall](https://wikido.isoftdata.com/index.php/The_GROUPing_pitfall)

Comment: Thanks LukStorms. I am new and that article is very descriptive of my problem. so I need multiple statements in the joins. I will try to figure this out @LukStorms

Comment: @Sbleezy Btw, not sure if it'll help. But I sometimes prefere a `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN... THEN someID END)` over a `SUM(CASE WHEN... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @LukStorms Im still having a bunch of issues with the query. Are you not able to left join and sum, count, or do any aggregate functions?

Comment: @CetinBasoz Im still having a bunch of issues. Ill try to import more code. essentially can you not left join and use any aggregate functions?

Comment: @Sbleezy, I am afraid you got me wrong about images. You still don't have some sample data and the desired output. How in the world, people here would determine which data come from where. You want answer that is deucted from your existing code ewhich might be wrong. Please supply sample data and be sure that data is readable (your current text is now worse than images, no commas or no formatting making it very hard to read).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Please look now. Let me know if I can make it any more clearer

Comment: @Sbleezy,close but not quite. In first 2 images you have the sample data. In SSMS, rightclick the square on top left, it should select all data and select copy with headers. Paste it here as sample data. And also write as simple text what should be the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a notepad scribble in a dark tube

```
SELECT tube.Ingot
, COUNT(tube.Piece) AS NumberOfTubes
, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL 
        THEN tube.Piece END) AS NumberOfTubesRejected
, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL
         AND RIGHT(tube.Piece,1)%2 = 0
        THEN tube.Piece END) AS NumberOfEvenTubesRejected,
, COUNT(CASE 
        WHEN tube.AcceptedBy IS NULL 
         AND RIGHT(tube.Piece,1)%2 = 1
        THEN tube.Piece END) AS NumberOfOddTubesRejected
, COALESCE(SUM(rework.NumberRejectedByIDDefects), 0) AS NumberRejectedByIDDefects
FROM dbo.Tube AS tube
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT TubeRework.Tube_#
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN ReworkCode.CodeNum in (4,5,6)
          THEN 1 END) AS NumberRejectedByIDDefects
  FROM dbo.TubeRework AS TubeRework
  JOIN dbo.ReworkCode AS ReworkCode 
    ON ReworkCode.ReworkCode_# = TubeRework.ReworkCode_#
  WHERE ReworkCode.CodeNum in (4,5,6)
  GROUP BY TubeRework.Tube_#
) rework ON rework.Tube_# = tube.Tube_#
GROUP BY tube.Ingot
```

Comment: @Sbleezy No idea if this works

Comment: Hey man this worked. I really appreciate it... If I could thumb up, I would. Have a great day

Comment: @Sbleezy You could approve the solution. ;)  But the idea is just that when you join in a many-to-many relationship, that to get the numbers right, that it has to be brought to a many-to-one relationship. Else you got monkey poop.